# JQuery Mobile: After changePage navbar is not working on target page until I manually refresh the browser

Tags: jquery

I have the problem that the navbar is not working on the target page (login.php), after changePage has been invoked from the login page (index.php).

I have 3 files

1. index.php - Login Mask
2. login.js - Contains the changePage
3. login.php - Contains the navbar that is not working

This is index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scal=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <div id="page" data-role="page">  
   <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h1>
     Carpooling
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <form>
     <div id="loginForm">
      <h2>
       Login
      </h2>
      <div id="usernameDiv" data-role="field-contain">
       <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" />
      </div>
      <div id="passwordDiv" data-role="field-contain">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
      </div>
      <div id="loginButtonDiv" data-role="field-contain">
       <button name="login" type="submit" data-inline="true">
        Login
       </button>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>  
   <div id="footer" data-role="footer">
    <h1>
     Copyright &copy; Bj&ouml;rn Karpenstein
    </h1>
   </div>    
  </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

This is login.js:

```html
$(function() {
   $('form').submit(function(){
  if(validateUsername() && validatePassword())
  {
   $.post("services/auth.php", $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
    if (response == 'true')
    {
      showSuccess('You will be redirected in a moment!');
      setTimeout(function(){
       $.mobile.changePage('login.php', {transition: "slide", reloadPage: true, changeHash: false});
      }, 2000);
    }
    else
    {
      showError(response);
    }
   });
  }
  
  function validateUsername() {
   if($('#username').val().length === 0)
   {
    showError('The Username can not be empty!');
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
    return true;
   }
   
   return false;
  }
  
  function validatePassword() {
   if($('#password').val().length === 0)
   {
    showError('The Password can not be empty!');
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
    return true;
   }
   
   return false;   
  }  
  
  function showSuccess(message){
   $('<div class="ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui_body_success ui-corner-all"><h1>'+message+'</h1></div>').css({ "display": "block", "opacity": 0.96, top: $(window).scrollTop() + 100 })
    .appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )
    .delay( 2000 )
    .fadeOut( 400, function(){
    $(this).remove();
   });
  }

  function showError(message){
   $('<div class="ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui_body_error ui-corner-all"><h1>'+message+'</h1></div>').css({ "display": "block", "opacity": 0.96, top: $(window).scrollTop() + 100 })
    .appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )
    .delay( 2000 )
    .fadeOut( 400, function(){
    $(this).remove();
    });
  }
    
  return false; 
 });
 });
```

This is login.php:

```html
<?php
 // ob_start();
 include_once('../services/session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Ohne den viewort ist es wie ne Desktopanwendung -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <div id="page" data-role="page">
   <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h1>
     Fahrtenliste
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <p>
     This is index
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="login.php" data-icon="grid">List rides</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#add_ride" data-icon="plus" data-rel="dialog">Add ride</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#list_users" data-icon="grid">List users</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#add_user" data-icon="plus">Add user</a></li>      
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="add_ride" data-role="dialog">
   <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h1>
     Add ride
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <div id="rideForm">
     <label for="fahrtUserName">Ride creator <?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?></label>
     <div id="fahrtUserName" data-role="field_contain">
      <input type="text" name="fahrt_username" value="<?php 
        echo $_SESSION['user_email']." <-> ";
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
        {
         echo "Die session hatja nix";
        } 
      ?>" readonly="readonly" id="fahrt_username" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div id="list_users" data-role="page">
   <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h1>
     List users
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <p>
     List users
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="login.php" data-icon="grid">List rides</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#add_ride" data-icon="plus">Add ride</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#list_users" data-icon="grid">List users</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#add_user" data-icon="plus">Add user</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div id="add_user" data-role="page">
   <div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h1>
     Add user
    </h1>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <p>
     Add user
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="login.php" data-icon="grid">List rides</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#add_ride" data-icon="plus">Add ride</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#list_users" data-icon="grid">List users</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php#add_user" data-icon="plus">Add user</a></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>   
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: open the javascript console and report any errors it shows.

Comment: Hi there are no errors shown :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that i cannot use changePage when i am using several pages in one target site.

What i did is i changed

```
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $.mobile.changePage('login.php', {transition: "slide", reloadPage: true, changeHash: false});
                    }, 2000);
```

to

```
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        // $.mobile.changePage('login.php', {transition: "slide", reloadPage: true, changeHash: false});
                        window.location='login.php';
                    }, 2000);
```